# Audio shiurim Meseches Kesubos

Tags: tosfot

Quick question: Is anyone aware of somewhere online that I would be able to download audio shiurim on meseches kesubos that include tosfos?
I need primarily on the first chapter. Thanks

Comment: When you say "that include tosfos" do you mean including a verbal reading of Tosfos within the shiur? Or a shiur that incorporates Tosfos's insights into the explanation?

Comment: I would rather a shiur that reads the tosfos inside, but i'll take whatever I can get.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://www.yutorah.org/search/?category=0,234212&series=4000) is a list of Kesubos shiurim at [YUTorah](https://www.yutorah.org), filtered to the daily shiurim at YU on Kesubos. It appears that various Roshei Yeshiva have given shiur on the first Perek, many of whom discuss Tosfos.